# R - Read.csv importing incorrectly due to column names missing

Tags: r, import

I have a CSV file that's missing column names. The CSV file has 16 columns, but only 9 columns have column names and the rest do not. Additionally, the 7 columns without column names also do not have any data in the first 8 rows.

When i use read.csv(my_file), R loads a dataframe with only 9 columns. It takes the other 7 columns and puts them at the bottom of 7 of the 9 first columns, which is a pain. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Best,

EDIT: let me know if i should provide my code / the CSV file. didn't attach at first on the off-chance that this is a common problem and could be solved without the CSv.

Comment: not sure how i would attach a CSV or even if i can actually

Comment: read.csv should deal with this out of the box, IF the separating commas are present (even if the values are not). Can't you just add them like `a,b,c,,,` instead of `a,b,c` if it's just a few rows?

Comment: i don't think the separating commas are present, since sep = "," doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: i have to read in hundreds of CSVs in this format, so manually adding column names, even for a few columns, would be a hassle.

Comment: Could you specify the number of columns for it to read in by writing the column names out? Something like this `df = read.table(file = "file", 
                  fill = TRUE, sep = ",",
                   col.names=paste("column", 1:7, sep="_")`?

Answer (score -1):

Take this example csv 'tmp.csv':

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9,10,11
```

Then you can parse it with the following command:

```
read.csv('tmp.csv', col.names=letters[1:5], fill=TRUE, header=TRUE)
```

This reads the header but ignores it, replacing it with your custom column names. Rows with missing values are automatically padded with NA.

Comment: @Canovice Glad it worked. I added an answer so it can be closed.

Answer (score -1):

You can read it in by specifying the number of columns like this:

```
df = read.table(file = "file", fill = TRUE, sep = ",", col.names=paste("column", 1:7, sep="_")
```